# Nginx - Django - Gunicorn: Large file uploads stalled after 30 seconds

Tags: django, file, nginx, upload, gunicorn

I am trying to upload a large file (50mb to multiple GB) to my django website. I use the regular file upload method described in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/). It works fine for smaller files.
I am serving the website with Nginx -> Gunicorn -> Django.

When the filesize is larger and the upload of the file **takes longer than 30 seconds**, the upload request will get "[stalled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubI1Y.png)" as chrome calls it and just freeze.

I originally thought this was a limit with nginx because the error.log said:

> 2018/08/03 01:13:09 [error] 1065#1065: *3 client intended to send too large body: 30681744 bytes,(...)

So I tweaked the following settings:

nginx.conf: ( in the http block)

```
client_max_body_size 100m;
client_body_buffer_size 100m;
client_body_timeout 120;
```

sites-available/host: ( in the server block)

```
send_timeout 120;
client_max_body_size 100m;
client_body_buffer_size 100m;
client_body_timeout 120;
```

After tweaking these, the error message has gone away.

The gunicorn log gives no further information. However, the documentation told me to start gunicorn with the --timeout 300 flag, so I did.

The file however **still does not upload** and "stalls" after 30 seconds of time.

Is this stalling a browser-issue? I remember uploading huge files with apache and PHP with no problems. Am I missing a django configuration?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.. The issue was with dropzone.js which I completely overlooked..
See [Large file upload - Request gets cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512084/large-file-upload-request-gets-cancelled)